# In SquareSpace, how do I hide appointment types if slots available equals 0?

Tags: css, squarespace

We offer group classes using appointment types. When a class is sold out, I don't want it to show on the website. The website shows appointment types using the Scheduling block.

When slots are no longer available, the appointment types still show in the Scheduling block. If a client clicks one of the sold out appointment types, they get a weird message stating "There are no appointments available between [date] and [date]." I'd rather the booked classes no longer show.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

simply include some custom javascript like this to get the amount available and hide the list of appointments if 0

1. Access the Code Injection Panel:

   - Log in to your Squarespace account.
   - Go to the Home menu.
   - Click on "Settings."
   - Click on "Advanced."
   - Click on "Code Injection."
2. Identify the Appointment Block:

   - Find the section of your site where the appointment block is located.

then enter this and make a code block, add said code block to your appointment page

```html
<script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // Check the availability here
      var slotsAvailable = /* Your logic to get the available slots count */;

      // Hide or show the appointment types based on availability
      if (slotsAvailable === 0) {
         document.getElementById('yourAppointmentTypeElementID').style.display = 'none';
      }
   });
</script>
```